# Plugin to upload as well as manage (e.g delete) photos in one container

Tags: jquery, wordpress, laravel, plugins

As in the title, I'm looking for a plugin of some sorts to:

- load the photos from the server (path)
- display them (preferably with an option to add checkboxes for multi
  delete)
- upload more photos
- manage said photos (e.g delete them [can be done outside tbh, as long as the checkboxes are possible])

Basically something like WordPress gallery manager.
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Edit: Sorry, was in rush before.
Use-case 1 -
Client is adding a new post. There's an empty container with an option to upload photos. Client selects photos and uploads them. They show up on the fly (with checkboxes), allowing for deletion in case of a wrong image.

Use-case 2-
Client is editing a post. Post already has 3 images linked to it. They show up with checkboxes next to them, allowing for multi-select and deletion on the fly. Client uploads 2 new photos, photos show up next to the already displayed photos.

Now that I actually wrote down those 2 use-cases I think we should just pump all the photos to a simple div and make it look fancy. In case of an upload, do it via ajax and then just render the partial with new photos. No plugins needed, although if anyone has done anything like that before, any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Extinox

Comment: Too broad. What are you using? Which part is giving you problems? How are images saved?

Comment: This question is to broad, but I think I can point you in the right direction.  With Laravel, it's more appropriate to refer to a "plugin" as a "package".  This might help you track down what you are looking for.  Almost all packages will come from Github.  So a reasonable search might be "laravel image manager github".  This returns several results, and without knowing more about your project, it's hard for anyone to tell you which package is best.  I suggest looking through these packages and selecting one that seems most appropriate.  Then, if you have issues, come back to stack for help.

Comment: Sorry, was in a rush before. Updated the question although I think I also answered myself while at it.
I used "plugin" because all I could think of was something like dropzone.js but with an ability to display already uploaded photos (pull the paths from the db) and place something like a checkbox next to them.